# Numpy Python Value error: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (1000,) and requested shape (1000,1)

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

I am making course in data science and I am pretty noob yet, while I as study this exercise, and try it to run it, it showed me this error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (1000,)  and requested shape (1000,1)"

Can you guys help me, solve this issue  ?

```
 import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    
    observations = 1000
    xs = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=(observations,1))
    zs = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (observations,1))
    
    inputs = np.column_stack((xs,zs))
    
    noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (observations,1))
    targets = 2*xs - 3*zs + 5 + noise
    
    targets = targets.reshape(observations,)
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot(xs, zs, targets)
    
    ax.set_xlabel('xs')
    ax.set_ylabel('zs')
    ax.set_zlabel('Targets')
    
    ax.view_init(azim=100)
    
    plt.show()
    
    targets = targets.reshape(observations,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```py
targets = targets.reshape(observations, 1)
```

Comment: didn't  work out

Comment: did you replace the line `targets = targets.reshape(observations,)` with `targets = targets.reshape(observations, 1)` or just added it at the end?